# Why would an organization use separate certs for identity and signing?

Tags: pki, cac

The DoD does this and I can't figure out the use case for it. They have different intermediate CAs, but I just can't think of a situation where they would want to distrust one CA and not the other.

What are the cons of just adding the Signing and Secure Email features to a cert that a user normally uses only to establish their ID?

Answer (score 1):

I think the original intent was to not give everyone encryption or signing certificates (i.e. some CACs just have the ID certs.)  This could've been accomplished by just setting the key usage, but since DoD has the luxury of being able to issue as many certs as they want at any time, and have the space on the smart card to support them, why not take advantage?

Comment: The disadvantage I think is more on the application side than the issuer/CAC side. Having multiple certs means you have to choose from a drop down which leads to users and sometimes even application developers choosing randomly what cert to use for ID, since they can both be used for ID.

Comment: I suppose they could've used a different set of CA's to sign the ID certs and then not put any other CA Root/Intermediate certs in the trust store except the ones used to issue ID certs.  Did I answer your question correctly?

Comment: They did use different intermediate certs to sign the "email" and "ID" certs, but my question is why that would ever matter. I can't think of one scenario where the correct thing to do would be to revoke trust to a person's email cert and not his ID cert.

Why would an application trust only the ID cert? I don't know how most people do it but in our test environment we just trust the DoD root CAs.

I do see what you're saying and I understand they CAN do a lot of things, but my question is really why have they or would they. Thanks for giving it a shot though.

Comment: In this case, I imagine it's less of a trust issue and more of an administrative separation, or partitioning. As @Sanjeev said, many sites using the ID certificate for authentication would only include the DOD ID CA-XX root in their trust stores, removing the need for the user to choose the correct certificate. Of course, there are just as many improperly configured ones as well. The concepts of least privilege and privilege separation also apply here, and would explain why they issue multiple certificates, each with a single specific usage. Overkill? Maybe. Paranoid? A bit. But if it works...